# How to render dynamic forms properly in Angular Reactive Forms?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have an API request that returns JSON array like the following:

```json
{
  "address": {
    "addressLine1": "499 Linden Boulevard",
    "addressLine2": "Apt 4b",
    "city": "Moraida",
    "province": "Kansas",
    "postalCode": "21763",
    "country": "USA"
  },
  "phones": [
    {
      "phoneNumber": "+1 (887) 502-2245",
      "phoneType": 3
    },
    {
      "phoneNumber": "+1 (823) 536-7452",
      "phoneType": 1
    }
  ],
  "email": "latti.sh@hotmail.com"
}
```

the "phones" JSON array is dynamic.. meaning that it might have one item or multiple or none..
I am trying to use Dynamic Reactive Forms so I have defined my form group like the following

```js
addressInfoForm = new FormGroup({
  addressLine1: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  addressLine2: new FormControl('', []),
  city: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  province: new FormControl('', []),
  postalCode: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  country: new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }, [Validators.required]),
  email: new FormControl('', [Validators.email]),
  phones: this.fb.array([this.fb.control('')]),
});
```

and when I get my JSON response in the `onInit()` method, I am setting the form values like this:

```js
this.addressInfoForm.setValue({
  addressLine1: this.clientIdentInfo.address.addressLine1,
  addressLine2: this.clientIdentInfo.address.addressLine2,
  city: this.clientIdentInfo.address.city,
  province: this.clientIdentInfo.address.province,
  postalCode: this.clientIdentInfo.address.postalCode,
  country: this.clientIdentInfo.address.country,
  email: this.clientIdentInfo.email,
  // how to set the phones
});
```

I did build the get phones() and AddPhone() methods like this.

```js
get phones() {
  return this.addressInfoForm.get('phones') as FormArray;
}

AddPhone() {
  this.phones.push(this.fb.control(''));
  this.phones.push(this.fb.control(''));
}
```

in my html, I am trying to populate the phones and have the ability of adding a new phone as well through `AddPhone()` method like this:

```html
<form *ngFor="let phone of phones.controls; let i=index;" 
   [formGroupName]="i" 
   formArrayName="phones">
        <mat-grid-list cols="4" rowHeight="90px" gutterSize="10px">
          <mat-grid-tile  [colspan]="1">
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="form-field">
              <mat-label>Phone {{i + 1}}</mat-label>
              <input matInput class="input-field" formControlName="phoneNumber">
              <mat-icon matSuffix>local_phone</mat-icon>
            </mat-form-field>
          </mat-grid-tile>
          <mat-grid-tile>
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="form-field">
              <mat-label>Phone Type</mat-label>
              <mat-select formControlName="phoneType">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let type of phoneTypes" [value]="type.phoneTypeId">
                  {{ type.phoneTypeName }}
                </mat-option>
              </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
          </mat-grid-tile>
        </mat-grid-list>
      </form>
```

Unfortunately, this isn't working! Can somebody help me achieve this the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U need to add phone controls to phone array with respective to your result and patch the value to the phones formarray.

```
   this.addressInfoForm.patchValue({
      addressLine1: result.address.addressLine1,
      addressLine2: result.address.addressLine1,
      city: result.address.city,
      province: result.address.province,
      postalCode: result.address.postalCode,
      country: result.address.country,
      email: result.email
    });

    for (let i = 0; i < result.phones.length - 1; i++) {
      this.AddPhone();
    }

    result.phones.forEach((item, index) => {
      this.phones.get(index.toString()).patchValue({
        phoneNumber: item.phoneNumber,
        phoneType: item.phoneType
      });
    });
```

Here's the stackblitz example Of your's with solution :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bhclwz?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: What if I want to populate the phone type (ex: 1:home, 2:cell, 3:work).. for some reason, it is not working out for me.. each time the user clicks add phone, a phone text box and a drop down menu of the phone type should populate

Comment: Ok as per your input i will make the changes in my stackblitz. but for your requirement you need to push formGroup to the Formarray

Comment: Check now , i have updated my answer and stackblitz as per your inputs @Riad

Comment: Yes, this is what I am doing but for some reason I am getting 
Error: Cannot find control with name: '0'
Error: Cannot find control with path: '0 -> phoneNumber'
Error: Cannot find control with path: '0 -> phoneType'

I am updating my html

Comment: No, it is not.. I am getting errors in my console.. I feel like I am missing something

Comment: Error: Cannot find control with name: '0' Error: Cannot find control with path: '0 -> phoneNumber' Error: Cannot find control with path: '0 -> phoneType'

Comment: I already updated my html in the question

Comment: don't use ngFor , formArrayName, and FormGroup in same element refer the stackblitz

Comment: Damn! I missed that

Comment: @Msk_Satheesh There is only one bug in this solution.. if the array of phones or emails was empty, then it will create one empty phone/email anyways